# Magento 2 -Problem with Braintree Method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, bug, braintree

[image]

I have a problem with magento 2.2, I have enabled the payment method braintree but this is the result, I can not enter the card data, the form is corrupt, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

There are several things that could potentially cause this issue. One of the more common reasons is that a theme, or plugin is causing a conflict which results in unintended issues with the Hosted Fields form's styling.

I would first start by disabling or removing any themes you may have installed to see if that resolves the issue. I would also recommend checking your Magento logs and your dev tool's console to make sure there are no errors.

If you still cannot locate the cause of the issue you can reach out to Braintree Support for assistance. I would also recommend reaching out to the developer of your Magento extension as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in Magento 2.4 also but braintree domain blocked in third paty[Consent Manager] extension hosted server. Once braintree whitelisted and card form loaded as expected.